# What does invalidateHttpSession do in Spring security ?

Tags: java, spring

I have problem understaing `JSessionId` and how it works.

I'm implementing a `/logout` Rest endpoint for my web app:

```
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK))
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(
            new JWTAuthenticationFilter(userDetailsServiceBean()),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

When I make a POST call to `/logout`, I still get the `JSESSIONID` cookie in the response from the server. And when I make a call to an endpoint that needs authentication:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/greeting",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public Greeting doGreeting(Principal principal, SecurityContextHolder auth) {
    String userId = principal.getName();
    Greeting greeting = new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, userId));
    return greeting;
}
```

I can still get the `principial` working. What is the use of `JSESSIONID` ? How does it compare with Authentication methods ?

Note: I use JWT for authentication. I send a JWT token in the header of my requests.

Comment: Why are you using a JSESSIONID if you are in a stateless environment (JWT) ? BTW If you are using JWT you need to disable session creation with `http
    .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)`

Comment: I don't set the JSESSIONID anywhere in my code! I'm using Spring Boot. Is there a possibility that it sets it itself and I need to turn it off ?

Comment: To turn it off `http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)` you can see the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/http/SessionCreationPolicy.html) for more information

Comment: What does invalidateHttpSession do ? is it only responsible to deal with JSESSIONID ?

Comment: I used http.csrf().disbale().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).... and it still sets JSESSIONID cookie

Comment: you need to clean your browser cookies. Did you see still see the `set-cookie` header in the http response when you log-in ?

Comment: Yeah, I had to delete the cookie from postman. does it mean that I don't need  invalidateHttpSession anymore ?

Comment: yes you don't need it anymore as it will not create any session when using `SessionCreati‌​onPolicy.STATELESS`